# Getting data from an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am doing a project (Android app) for uni and after a bit of help I have a login screen as per the code below:

```
//Do once the "Login" button is clicked
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //get the users name and password
    EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    String name = editName.getText().toString();
    //EditText editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserPassword);
    //String password = editPassword.getText().toString();

    //create an Intent object and pass it the name and password
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserLoggedInScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("userName", name);
    //intent.putExtra("userPassword", password);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have commented out the the password bit for now just to get the username bit working. The aim is to click the button and put the text input into textUserName by the user into the String name. Then pass that through to activity UserLoggedInScreen.

Then in UserLoggedInScreen collect the data:

```
public class UserLoggedInScreen extends Activity
{
TextView welcomeUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userloggedinscreen);

    //get the Intent Object from LapMasterActivity
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //get the data from the Intent Object
    String userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName");
    //String userPassword = intent.getStringExtra("userPassword");

    welcomeUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    welcomeUser.setText(userName);
}
```

When I try running it and clicking the button in the opening activity I get the usual "Unfortunately UserLoggedInScreen has stopped working".

I think this bit might be the error:

```
welcomeUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
```

I tried changing txtUserName to userName but that didn't help either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing As *Bappy* said Register Your activity so that it can be detected at runtime.

```
<activity android:name="UserLoggedInScreen">
</activity>
```

Second thing

```
welcomeUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
```

You are using same id, are you doing it intentionally??

Pleas Check id of TextView of `UserLoggedInScreen`.

Comment: UserLoggedInScreen is in the manifest file and was loading properly before adding the extra data. You have highlighted the same as me in regards to what was wrong and your correct I was using the incorrect TextView. It should have been one I created in UserLoggedInScreen (the recipient) not txtUserName or userName from the starting activity. It's also working now. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

have you maked activity in AndroidManifast for Second Class........

```
<activity android:name="UserLoggedInScreen"></activity>
```